# One-size-fits-all package manager for ubuntu?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu

I’m a mac user and I was thinking about switching to Ubuntu since Apple is becoming a little to expensive for me. One of the first things I couldn’t live without is a good package manager.
Now, brew has a lot of things. Actually 99% of the time I needed something I wrote `brew install coolstuff` and I was done. With Ubuntu all I found is `apt-get` and `yum` and they basically can’t do anything. **Want to install java?** nope. **Want to get docker?** Go download it yourself. **You need a game to relax?** Remember to type `sudo` because every game apparently needs to write to the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get` is Ubuntu's package manager. If you use a package manager from another distro, Bad Things May Happen™. I think you're mistaken in thinking that brew has more content than Ubuntu's repositories; you might need to read up on [how to use it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto).

If you're looking to add more content to the package manager, you may want to [enable the Universe and Multiverse repositories](https://askubuntu.com/a/89100/321124), or look for a [PPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Package_Archive) that has what you want.